# Все значения массива null, но так быть не должно!

Tags: java, массивы, ооп, классы, циклы

Возник вопрос, создала класс, в конструкторе цикл, где заполнила массив значениями, но при создании объекта и выводе на консоль все значения массива null. Совершенно не понимаю в чем ошибка:(
Звездочками указала проблемные зоны, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так(
[image: выдается ошибка]

```
package com.company;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

 ** public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      BigInteger[] d = new BigInteger[128];
        BigInteger[] d1 = new BigInteger[128];
        Bits bits = new Bits(d, d1);
        System.out.println(bits.getBits()); **

    }
}

class Bits {
    private final int size = 128;                 //поля экземпляра
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private BigInteger bstr2, bstr1;
    BigInteger[] nums1 = new BigInteger[128];
    BigInteger[] nums2 = new BigInteger[128];
    private BigInteger bits1 = new BigInteger(size, random);
    private BigInteger bits2 = new BigInteger(size, random);


    public Bits (BigInteger[] b1, BigInteger[] b2) {   //конструктор

       ** while (!bits1.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            bstr1 = bits1.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
            for (int i=0; i<128; i++) {
                nums1[i] = nums1[i].add(bstr1);
            }
            bits1 = bits1.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
        }
        nums1 = b1; **

        while (!bits2.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            bstr2 = bits2.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
            for (int i=0; i<128; i++) {
                nums2[i] = nums2[i].add(bstr2);
            }
            bits2 = bits2.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
        }
        nums2 = b2;

    }

    public String getBits() {
        return Arrays.toString(nums1);
    }

    public void ANDBits () {}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алиса, по-моему всё элементарно.
Посмотрите на этот кусочек кода:

```
while (!bits1.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
    bstr1 = bits1.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
    for (int i=0; i<128; i++) {
        nums1[i] = nums1[i].add(bstr1);
}
```

Вы проинициализировали `nums1`, но не заполнили его, все его значения равны null. А вот тут: `nums1[i].add(bstr1)` вы пытаетесь у этого null *(потому что nums1[i] == null, проверьте дебаггером)* вызвать метод `add()`.

Comment: Тогда не подскажете, как решить проблему? Cделать так, чтобы массив заполнился значениями ```bstr1 = bits1.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2));```

Comment: Замените `nums1[i] = nums1[i].add(bstr1);` на  `nums1[i] = bits1.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2));`. Должно помочь.

Comment: И сделайте ту же самую операцию для следующего цикла. У вас там тоже идёт вызов add у null.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, но ваш ответ вывел меня из заблуждения, спасибо!

Comment: Проведите рефакторинг. Уберите логику из конструктора и создайте отдельный метод. Вам же будет проще. Если ответ вам помог или отвечает на вопрос, который вы задали, отметьте его решением.

Comment: Ох, ну когда я решу, то обязательно отвечу)